# Coordinate transformation with $d\xi = \frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+a^2}}dx$ and $d\eta = \frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+a^2}}dy$

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, differential-geometry

I am recently working on the coordinate transformation in 2D image space. For example, by following the certain mapping, $ x = f(\xi, \eta)$ and $ y = g(\xi, \eta)$, image in $(x,y) $ coordinates is transformed to $(\xi, \eta)$ space.

The relationship between $(x,y) $ and $(\xi, \eta)$ is defined as follows.

$$
d\xi = \frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+a^2}}dx \\
d\eta = \frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+a^2}}dy
$$

From the relationship above, I want to obtain more direct mapping of those coordinates (ex. $x=f(\xi,\eta)$ and $y=g(\xi,\eta)$). To get it, my derivation is as follows,

For simplify the writings, let $b^2 = y^2+a^2$. Then,

$$
d\xi = \frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+b^2}}dx
$$

Put $x = b \sinh{z}$ and use $dx = \cosh{z}dz$. 
\begin{align}
    d\xi &= \frac{1}{\sqrt{b^2 \sinh{z}+b^2}}b\cosh{z}dz \\
    &= \frac{1}{\sqrt{b^2(\cosh{z})^2}} b\cosh{z}dz \\
    &= dz
\end{align}

Therefore, 
$$\begin{align}
    \int d\xi &= \int dz\\
    \xi &= z + c \\
    &= \sinh^{-1}(\frac{x}{b})+c\\
    &= \sinh^{-1}(\frac{x}{\sqrt{y^2+a^2}})+c
\end{align}$$
Likewise, derive y. Then, 
$$\begin{equation}
    \xi = \sinh^{-1}(\frac{x}{\sqrt{y^2+a^2}}) \tag{*}\label{*}
\end{equation}$$
$$\begin{equation}
    \eta = \sinh^{-1}(\frac{y}{\sqrt{x^2+a^2}})
\end{equation}$$

I set $c = 0$ to map the center of the coordinates to the center of the other coordinate space ($x=0$ to $\xi=0$).

But what I want to get is the form $x = f(\xi, \eta)$ and $y = g(\xi, \eta)$. 
By applying $\sinh$ to both sides of equation \eqref{*}, we get

\begin{equation}
    \sinh{\xi} = \frac{x}{\sqrt{y^2+a^2}}
\end{equation}
and clearing the other variables other than x, 
\begin{equation}
    x = \sqrt{y^2+a^2} \sinh{\xi} \tag{a}\label{a}
\end{equation}
And same for y
\begin{equation}
    y = \sqrt{x^2+a^2} \sinh{\eta} \tag{b}\label{b}
\end{equation}

Putting y in equation \eqref{b} to \eqref{a}, 
\begin{align}
    x &= \sqrt{(x^2+a^2) \sinh^2{\eta}     +a^2} \sinh{\xi}\\
    x^2 &= ((x^2+a^2) \sinh^2{\eta}+a^2) \sinh^2{\xi}\\
    &= (x^2+a^2) \sinh^2{\eta}\sinh^2{\xi} + a^2\sinh^2{\xi}\\
    &= x^2 \sinh^2{\eta}\sinh^2{\xi} + a^2 \sinh^2{\xi}(1+\sinh^2{\eta})\\
    &= x^2 \sinh^2{\eta}\sinh^2{\xi} + a^2 \sinh^2{\xi}\cosh^2{\eta}
\end{align}
\begin{align}
    x^2 (1-\sinh^2{\eta}\sinh^2{\xi}) &= a^2 \sinh^2{\xi}\cosh^2{\eta}\\
    x^2 &= \frac{a^2 \sinh^2{\xi}\cosh^2{\eta}}{1-\sinh^2{\eta}\sinh^2{\xi}}\\
    x &= \frac{a \sinh{\xi}\cosh{\eta}}{\sqrt{1-\sinh^2{\eta}\sinh^2{\xi}}}\tag{c}\label{c}
\end{align}

And same for y.
\begin{equation}
    y = \frac{a \sinh{\eta}\cosh{\xi}}{\sqrt{1-\sinh^2{\eta}\sinh^2{\xi}}}\tag{d}\label{d}
\end{equation}

Final results \eqref{c} and \eqref{d} are the form I want. My question is, whether my derivation is right or not. I am confident until the equation $\eqref{*}$. But I am not sure after the equation $\eqref{*}$ because my experiment using this later part of the equations are not accurate. I think I missed something. I am not sure but I feel I should not insert $y$ from $\eqref{b}$ to $\eqref{a}$ because I got $\eqref{*}$ with the assumption that $x$ and $y$ are independent. But suddenly relationship between $x$ and $y$ seems to emerge after $\eqref{b}$ and $\eqref{a}$.

Could you follow my derivation and see if there is something wrong?

For your information, the paper I am referring to is 'http://mate.tue.nl/mate/pdfs/11468.pdf'.

Comment: As the paper itself stated, the one forms $d\xi$ and $d\eta$ are **non-exact**. This means that you cannot expect to recover $\xi,\eta$ as functions of $x,y$.

Comment: @WillieWong Thank you for your comment. I don't have a strong background but as far as I know, if this ODE is non-exact, isn't is solvable by using a proper integral factor? Could you give me more clues? I just want to transform an image from (x,y) coordinate to $(\xi,\eta)$ coordinate or vice versa and that is the idea of the paper in the link. Could you give me some advice regarding this transformation?

Comment: The point is that there is **no** "coordinate" $(\xi,\eta)$ where the coordinate differentials $d\xi$ and $d\eta$ obey the relation you wrote down. The transformation you seek is impossible. // and no, the method of integrating factors cannot be used in this case // this is not an ODE, but a system of partial differential equations.